# How do I test complex expressions with bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I can only do simply expressions like `1=1 and 0=1`

```
test 1 = 1 -a 0 = 1
```

But how to do complex expressions like `1=1 and (0=1 or 1=1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use multiple test calls:

```
test 1 = 1 && test 0 = 1 -o 1 = 1
```

or [[:

```
[[ 1 = 1 && (0 = 1 || 1 = 1) ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `test` or `[` ... `]` as long as you are careful, remembering that parentheses have to be escaped and terms have to be separated by spaces:

```
if [ \( a = a \) -a \( a = b -o b = b \) ]
then echo Yes
else echo No
fi
```

That echoes 'Yes' for me.  It is usually easier, though, to use the Bash and Korn shell `[[` ... `]]` operator instead; you don't have to do as much escaping.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered, but a couple of style tips you might consider (and maybe reject :-) ):

If you are the one writing it, and find it confusing, then maybe:

- Use extra () even if they are not needed, might make it clearer.
- Also maybe use nested loops instead of lots of and statements.

Answer (score 0):

Florian is mostly correct above, but keep in mind that bash also has arithmetic expansion which is a bit nicer when you are comparing variables.

See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) for more info.